# Query animate scrollTop not working in my flex box two column layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have build a two column site using flex box for layout with a two column layout. As I flushed out the site, I wanted to add animation to my local links using animate and scrollTop. The local links work fine without the javascript, but with the function it does not. I suspect it has to do with the layout, but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have build a fiddle to show my issue.

My links are in the left column, content on the right. I am using this function to do my animated scrolling

```
$('.scroll-to').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log('clicked on #' + href);
    $('.main-content').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - 10
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhwcou6e/1/)

I have a feeling I am close, but have spent a couple of hours trying to go this last few feet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your sandbox contains different code.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but as the above user said, you have the wrong JS Fiddle.

Comment: So sorry, I corrected the link.